# Python use variables in list in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how I can substitute a value into a list as it is iterated through. The reason for needing this is this is testing code and eventually there will be up-to 15/20 API calls to build with thousands of table_2_details entries.

Code:

```
table1 = ['table_1', 'getpost', 'url_1_<project_id>', 'filename_1']
table2 = ['table_2', 'getpost', 'url_2_<project_id>', 'filename_2']

api_calls = [table1, table2]

# Special treatment
table2_details = ['table_2_details', 'getpost', 'url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>', 'filename_2_details']

projects = ['proj1', 'proj2', 'proj3']
checklists = ['check1', 'check2', 'check3']

for project_id in projects:
    print(f"\n{project_id}")
    for call in api_calls:
        print(call[2])
        if call[0] == "table_2":
            for checklist_id in checklists:
                print(table2_details[2])
```

Current output:

```
proj1
url_1_<project_id>
url_2_<project_id>
url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>
url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>
url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>

proj2
url_1_<project_id>
url_2_<project_id>
url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>
url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>
url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>

proj3
url_1_<project_id>
url_2_<project_id>
url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>
url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>
url_2_details_<project_id>_<checklist_id>
```

I need to substitute in the project_id and checklist_id as shown by the <>

I'm new to Python so please if this is insane please point me in the right direction so I can learn.

Thank you for any help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use string formatting to do this, e.g. put formatting sequences in your strings like this:

```
table2_details = ['table_2_details', 'getpost', 'url_2_details_{project_id:}_{checklist_id:}', 'filename_2_details']
```

Then before you use any of the strings, run them through format like this:

```
for arg in table2_details:
    print(arg.format(project_id='foo', checklist_id='bar'))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Worked perfectly. print(call[2].format(project_id=project_id))

Answer (score 0):

you can build the `url` dynamically with data from the lists like

```
table2_details = ['table_2_details', 'getpost', 'url_2_details', 'filename_2_details']
...

for checklist_id in checklists:
  url = table2_details[2] + "_" + project_id + "_" + checklist_id
  print(url)
  # do something with this url
```

Comment: Thanks for this, only problem which I should of mentioned is the URL can contain the parameter in the middle of the URL. E.g. http://www.hey.com/project_id/status

Answer (score 0):

use format print.

```
table1 = ['table_1', 'getpost', 'url_1_{0}', 'filename_1']
table2 = ['table_2', 'getpost', 'url_2_{0}', 'filename_2']

api_calls = [table1, table2]

# Special treatment
table2_details = ['table_2_details', 'getpost', 'url_2_details_{0}_{1}', 'filename_2_details']

projects = ['proj1', 'proj2', 'proj3']
checklists = ['check1', 'check2', 'check3']

for project_id in projects:
    print "{}".format(project_id)
    for call in api_calls:
        print(call[2].format(project_id))
        if call[0] == "table_2":
            for checklist_id in checklists:
                print(table2_details[2].format(project_id, checklist_id))
```